# How to find all the solutions of the ODE: $y''=e^y$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following equation $$y''=e^y$$
With some help/hints from similar posts around the forums (and a generous dose of wolframalpha), I was able to simplify it as follows: $$y'=u(y) \Rightarrow y''=u'u\\ 
 u\frac{du}{dy}=e^y\\\frac{u^2}{2}=e^y+C \\ \therefore\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2(e^x+C)}}dy}=\pm dx $$ which gave me the following result:
$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{-C}}\arctan(\frac{\sqrt{e^y+C}}{\sqrt{-C}})=\pm x + C_{1} \text{ , } C > 0$$

I was given the answers (without any method) but they differ from mine (and quite drastically it seems).  The answers were: $$e^y\sin^2(C_{1}x+C_{2})=2C_{1}^2;\\e^y\sinh^2(C_{1}x+C_{2})=2C_{1}^2;\\e^y(x+C)^2=2$$
Have I gone wrong in my method for solving the ODE, or am I missing additional steps to simplify the result I got? (I am assuming I went wrong somewhere since I only found 1 supposed solution instead of 3)

Comment: Your solution es equivalent to second solution. The problem is that the improper integral depends on wheter $C>0$, $C=0$ or $C<0$

Comment: Ah that does make sense. Thank you!  I had initially thought I need to "evaluate" C (C>0, C=0, and C<0) after the solution is found.  No wonder I was only able to find one solution.  Again, thank you!

Comment: The first and second form are equivalent or complementary, the equivalence turning real constants into imaginary constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you got
$$
\frac{y'^2}2=e^y+C
$$
To get all unknown functions to the same level, considering $y$ and $e^y$ different levels, set $v=e^{-y/2}$, so that $v'=-\frac{y'}2e^{-y/2}$ and thus
$$
v'^2=\frac{y'^2}4e^{-y}=\frac12+\frac{C}2v^2.
$$
Depending on the sign of $C$ this is now an ellipse equation or a hyperbolic equation in $(v,v')$, or two lines for $C=0$. For these there are standard solution methods.

It turns out that all three forms in the reference answer are true for one of these cases.

Comment: Thank you! I must admit, I've been blindly following the method we were taught in class, but thinking of an appropriate substitution to make everything the same level, as you said, has just made something click.

Answer (score 2):

$$y''(x)=e^y$$

Hint:

Multiply both sides by $y'(x)$

$$y'y''=y'e^y$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2=\frac{dy}{dx}e^y$$

Now integrate both sides, what do you come up with?

Comment: This is essentially what the first part of the question text describes. The question proper asks about the second integration.

Answer (score 1):

There is anothe possible approach based on the switch of variables
$$y''=e^y \qquad \implies \qquad -\frac{x''}{[x']^3}=e^y$$
First, reduction of order $$p=y'\quad \implies \quad -\frac {p'}{p^3}=e^y\quad \implies \quad p=\pm \frac 1{\sqrt{2e^y+c_1}}$$
$$x'=\pm \frac 1{\sqrt{2e^y+c_1}}\quad \implies \quad x+c_2=\pm \frac{2 }{\sqrt{c_1}}\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2
   e^y+c_1}}{\sqrt{c_1}}\right)$$ Inversion
$$y=\log \left(-\frac{c_1}{1+\cosh \left(\pm\sqrt{c_1} 
   (x+c_2)\right)}\right)$$

Comment: I'm a little unsure how you get the $-\frac{x′′}{[x′]^3}=e^y$, could you perhaps elaborate a little? Are you manipulating $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to rewrite it as $dx$?